# What does "LBS" mean in the context of WAI?

Tags: haskell, haskell-wai

There are several identifiers in [WAI](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai) containing "LBS":

- [`Network.Wai.responseLBS`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-0.4.3/docs/Network-Wai.html#v:responseLBS)`:: Status -> ResponseHeaders -> ByteString -> Response`
- `-- | Store uploaded files in memory`
  [`lbsBackEnd`](https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/blob/b6d2e3cb525a61d7150600f9957002bb755bcb25/wai-extra/Network/Wai/Parse.hs#L78)`:: Monad m => ignored1 -> ignored2 -> m S.ByteString -> m L.ByteString`

I can't find anything in the WAI documentation that mentions "LBS". What does it mean?

Comment: My guess would be "lazy ByteString".

Comment: It is almost definitely what @DerekElkins said....  If you go to the hackage documentation, you can see that the input param is a lazy Bytestring https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.0.5.0/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Response, whereas there are other functions that create responses from non-lazy Bytestrings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Hackage documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.0.4.0/docs/Network-Wai.html):

> The overriding design principles here are performance and generality. 
>       To address performance, this library is built on top of the `conduit` 
>       and `blaze-builder` packages. The advantages of conduits over lazy IO 
>       have been debated elsewhere and so will not be addressed here. 
>       However, helper functions like `responseLBS` allow you to continue using 
>       lazy IO if you so desire.

so, yes, LBS does stand for [Lazy ByteString](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html).